# Understanding multivalued dependencies

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, rdbms, dbms

This is my first time studying multivalued dependencies and there is a question that was posted by my lecturer as a class exercise. I have an answer, but I'm not 100% sure it was right. Please let me know if my answer is complete and correct:

**Question**

[image: questions]

**My answer**

Multi-valued dependencies

- courseCode ↠ lecturerId
- courseCode ↠ (startDate, StartTime)
- (courseCode, startDate, StartTime) ↠ learnerId
- learnerId ↠ (courseCode, startDate)

Functional dependencies

- courseCode → (courseName, weeklyHours, noofWeeks)
- (courseCode, startDate,StartTime) → lecturerId
- (courseCode, lecturerId) → (startDate, StartTime)  *Note: I'm not sure if this is even needed*
- lecturerId → (lecturerName, lecturerEmail, lecturerGender)
- learnerId → (learnerName, learnerEmail)

Comment: Armstrong's axioms tell you *all* the FDs that hold when some do. There are similar axioms for MVDs. (See Wikipedia MVD.) Moreover you need to know *all* the FDs & MVDs that hold. (MVDs come in pairs.) You can do this by exhaustion, or there are algorithms. What *reference* does your class use? You need to use it. Perhaps the simplest definition for an MVD is that it corresponds to a binary JD--a table equals the join of two of its projections. This requires that you can phrase a table's *(characteristic) predicate* (statement template parameterized by columns) as the AND of two components'.

Comment: Please use [text inline any time you can](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Ie cut & paste (after ocr if necessary). Images should be supplemental or necessary. PS See my stackoverflow MVD answers.

Comment: What is the question? What is the assignment?